# Add content validation workflow in magento

Tags: php, content-management-system, magento

Is there a module or a way to add validation workflow when adding/editing/deleting a product, category or content in magento ?

The idea is to have a editor that edit contents and a validator that sees the content (preview it) and validates it.

### Another feature, is there a way to have 2 versions of the same content : published version and draft version ?

Another question :
 
If I override CMS Module to add content validation (override the way to access database to put published content and draft content). Is that possible ? I don't know yet how to develop magento modules so that I'm asking the question.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

The best practise in magento to put a validation on product and category or any model add / update is to use observers.

For catalog product validation add to your module config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <!-- catalog category event here -->
        <catalog_product_save_before>
            <observers>
                <validateproduct>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>myobserverfunction</method>
                </validateproduct>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_before>
   </events>
</adminhtml>
```

and then simply define a function in Yourmodule/Model/Observer with name myobserverfunction(), as follows:

```
class Mymodule_Model_Observer
{
    public function myobserverfunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {        
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();  
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: remember for back end save it is adminhtml... had it been from the frontend then it would be frontend tag.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, if you're talking about the CMS, you can enable version control which allows you to save updated copies of the content without publishing it. (Might be a Pro/Enterprise feature though, not sure.)

To enable version control on a CMS page, change "Under Version Control" to yes in the Page Information tab.

Comment: With version control will I have a page published and another version (newer) off line and awaiting for validation ?

Comment: As long as you hit the "Save" button and not "Save and Publish." You have to pay attention to which version of the page is published.